# How can I give my non-root user write permissions on a kubernetes volume mount?

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

From my understanding (based on this guide https://snyk.io/blog/10-kubernetes-security-context-settings-you-should-understand/), if I have the following security context specified for some kubernetes pod

```
securityContext:
  # Enforce to be run as non-root user
  runAsNonRoot: true
  # Random values should be fine
  runAsUser: 1001
  runAsGroup: 1001
  # Automatically convert mounts to user group
  fsGroup: 1001
  # For whatever reasons this is not working
  fsGroupChangePolicy: "Always"
```

I expect this pod to be run as user 1001 with the group 1001. This is working as expected, because running `id` in the container results in: `uid=1001 gid=1001 groups=1001`.

The file system of all mounts should automatically be accessible by user group 1001, because we specified `fsGroup` and `fsGroupChangePolicy`. I guess that this also works because when running `ls -l` in one of the mounted folders, I can see that the access rights for the files look like this: `-rw-r--r-- 1 50004 50004`. Ownership is still with the uid and gid it was initialised with but I can see that the file is now readable for others.

The question now is how can I add write permission for my `fsGroup` those seem to still be missing?

Comment: ime, and also stated in the docs: *By default, Kubernetes recursively changes ownership and permissions for the contents of each volume to match the fsGroup specified in a Pod's securityContext when that volume is mounted.* https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/#configure-volume-permission-and-ownership-change-policy-for-pods

Comment: So the stuff should be really owned by 1001 with your setup.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add an additional `init_container` in your pod/deployment/{supported_kinds} with the commands to give/change the permissions on the volume mounted on the pod to the userID which container is using while running.

```yaml
 initContainers:
  - name: volumepermissions
    image: busybox ## any image having linux utilities mkdir,echo,chown will work.
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    env:
      - name: "VOLUME_DATA_DIR"
        value: mountpath_for_the_volume
    command:
      - sh
      - -c
      - |
        mkdir -p $VOLUME_DATA_DIR
        chown -R 1001:1001 $VOLUME_DATA_DIR 

        echo 'Volume permissions OK ✓'
    volumeMounts:
      - name: data
        mountPath: mountpath_for_the_volume
```

<s>This is necessary when a container in a pod is running as a user other than root and needs write permissions on a mounted volume.</s>

if this is a helm template this init container can be created as a template and used in all the pods/deployments/{supported kinds} to change the volume permissions.

Update: As mentioned by @The Fool, it should be working as per the current setup if you are using Kubernetes v1.23 or greater. After v1.23 [securityContext.fsGroup and securityContext.fsGroupChangePolicy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/#configure-volume-permission-and-ownership-change-policy-for-pods) features went into GA/stable.

Comment: ah good point with the version. That may be the issue.

Comment: Okay I totally understand the init container approach, but would like to avoid it. As both of you mentioned that it should be working correctly on the right kubernetes version. Client Version is `v1.23.6` and Server Version is `v1.23.13`. We are using EKS with EFS as persistent volumes. As the kubernetes version seems to match, I can only think of EFS maybe not supporting fsGroup and fsGroupChangePolicy in the way it should be?

Comment: I think this confirms it: https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-efs-csi-driver/issues/125